# Group by with data expanding to new columns

Tags: python, r, pandas

How can I achieve the following in Python or R ?

Group by Surname and Given name, and move the Address and City to new columns on the grouped row

```
  Surname  Givename  Address  City
1   Name1 Givename1  Addr11 City11
2   Name1 Givename1  Addr12 City12
3   Name2 Givename2  Addr21 City21
4   Name2 Givename2  Addr22 City22
5   Name2 Givename2  Addr23 City23
```

To:

```
  Surname  Givename  Address  City  Address City  Address  City
1   Name1 Givename1  Addr11 City11  Addr12 City12
2   Name2 Givename2  Addr21 City21  Addr22 City22  Addr23 City23
```

I do not care about duplicate column names, it can look like that or with an additional address number

Comment: Could you also include what has already failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas: you can use [`groupby.cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) a helper series ,followed by [`unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with column formatting:

```
final=(df.assign(k=df.groupby(['Surname','Givename']).cumcount())
    .set_index(['Surname','Givename','k']).unstack().sort_index(level=1,axis=1))
final.columns=[f'{a}_{b}' for a,b in final.columns.values]
print(final)
```

---

```
                  Address_0  City_0 Address_1  City_1 Address_2  City_2
Surname Givename                                                       
Name1   Givename1    Addr11  City11    Addr12  City12       NaN     NaN
Name2   Givename2    Addr21  City21    Addr22  City22    Addr23  City23
```

*Note: you can do a `final=final.reset_index()` if you want the `Surname` and `Givename` as columns not index.*

Comment: Is there a solution to this same thing but in R?

Comment: @BenjaminKrick Unfortunately I am not aware of R. You may want to post a question if you do not find anything similar for R :)